# Warning: PATH set to RVM ruby but GEM_HOME and/or GEM_PATH not set, see: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3212

Tags: rvm, aws-cloud9

I use AWS Cloud9 as my development environment. Occasionally, when I open an new terminal tab (Alt T),  I get the error message below.

`Warning: PATH set to RVM ruby but GEM_HOME and/or GEM_PATH not set, see: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3212`

Answer (score 0):

Run `>sudo reboot`

Usually there will be one terminal tab open that does not contain the error message,
I keep this tab open and close any other tabs that show the error message.

Then, in the 'clean terminal tab', I run `sudo reboot`.  AWS Cloud9 will show a 'Reconnecting' message, and when it has completed reconnecting,
I open a new terminal tab (Alt T) and the error is gone. Then I close the original tab that I ran sudo reboot in.
Now I can open as many terminal tabs as I need with no error messages.